# Is it safe to use std::auto_ptr in std::map?

Tags: c++, stl, smart-pointers, c++03

I am aware that you have to be careful with auto pointers (and why), especially with the STL. But I don't see a problem with this:

```
std::map<T1, std::auto_ptr<T2> >;
```

Is this safe?

---

I see how it would break in an `std::vector`, because it has to copy its items from time to time, but is this also true for the value type of an `std::map`?

---

Edit: Apparently, regardless whether it's safe, I cannot (technically) populate the map, but I'll leave the question open for theoretical considerations. Otherwise, consider it closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not safe. Technically, `std::auto_ptr` doesn't meet the requirement of *CopyConstructible* or *Assignable* because copies made using `auto_ptr`'s copy constructor or copy assignment operator aren't equivalent to the source of the copy after the copy operation. These requirements must be met for any type used with any standard container.

You may find that you appear to get the behaviour you expect on one implementation for one particular use case but if you violate the requirements of the container you can't expect your code to work in all situations.

Answer (score 0):

Still not safe.  If nothing else, the first time you retrieved the pointer from the map you would transfer ownership and make it invalid.

There is an extremely narrow valid use case for auto_ptr.  The only one I can remember coming across is when an object wants to make it explicitly clear that it takes ownership and responsibility for a pointer that you hand it.

Comment: Doesn't element access in a map return a *reference* to the value type? I.e. `std::auto_ptr<T2>&`. That does not create a new `auto_ptr` object.

Comment: But a lot of times programmers tend to accept the return value by copy (int value = myMap[key];) and that would transfer ownership if the value type were auto_ptr

Comment: If you *always* use the reference directly or assign to a reference, including function arguments, macros, initializations, etc, then it's probably fine so long as the implementation of std::map does nothing weird.  That's more burden on my memory and vigilance that I would choose to take on just for the questionable benefit of using auto_ptr when there are alternatives such as the TR1 smart pointers or Boost.